# ASP- Get a GridRow value / OnClick method

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm working on a C#/ASP 4.0 project where I'm trying to make a shopping cart application.

There is a GridView on my Products page that shows all of the items, and I want the user to be able to click an "Add to Cart" button field in this GridView which will, obviously, add an item to their cart.

I'm having issues actually setting an OnClick event for the gridview, though? That doesn't seem to be available in the Event menu in the Properties. Additionally, I can't seem to figure out how to get the specific row, either. I have method that does this...

```
 int productID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Text);
 AddToCart(productID);
```

But I have no idea how to figure out n, or how to have this method get called when they click that ButtonField in the gridview.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

First, add a template field to the gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add to Cart">
   <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button id="bthAddToCart"
              CommandArgument'<%#Eval("ProductID")%>'
               OnClick="bthAddToCart_Click"
               Text="Add to Cart"
              runat="server"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now, add the handler for the Click event of the button:

```
protected void bthAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   Button button = (Button)sender;
   int productID = Convert.ToInt32(button.CommandArgument);
   AddToCart(productID);
}
```

Comment: What exactly IS a template column?

Comment: @user1189566 on a DataGrid the element is called TemplateColumn, on GridViews the equivalent is a template field. See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatecolumn.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the template fields like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header Text Here">
        <ItemTemplate>
            CONTROL TO SHOW COLUMN DATA
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header Text Here">
        <ItemTemplate>
            CONTROL TO SHOW COLUMN DATA
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header Text Here">
        <ItemTemplate>
            CONTROL TO SHOW COLUMN DATA
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header Text Here">
        <ItemTemplate>
            CONTROL TO SHOW COLUMN DATA
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="30px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" CommandName="AddToCart"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    No Data Found.
</EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then on your code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
    {
        int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        AddToCart(ProductID);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OnRowCommand` event of the grid view. More details: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowcommand.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OnRowCommand Event for Gridview. Use Following Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header Text Here">
        <ItemTemplate>
            CONTROL TO SHOW COLUMN DATA
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="30px">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddToCart" runat="server" Text="Add To Cart" CommandName="AddToCart"
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:GridView>
```

In C# Code use following code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Add To Cart")
    {
        int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        AddToCart(ProductID);
    }
}
```